# How to generate actions for dynamically created CheckBoxes in android?

Tags: android

I have dynamically generated CheckBoxes on the table in android . Now I want to know which CheckBox was checked, how can I determine this ? Need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Use on check change listener

Comment: Add your code and layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [View.setTag(object)](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) to tag the Checkbox with something distinct like an id. Then when the [OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) fires, you can check the tag with View.getTag() to see which one was clicked.